# Subsetting the netCDF4 dataset [Python, xarray]

Tags: python, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray, temperature

I have a following [netCDF4 dataset](https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov//Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/Monthlies/surface_gauss/air.2m.gauss.day.ltm.1991-2020.nc) which is basically a long term mean of global daily 2m air temperature. It has lat/lon graticule, each node of which has one temperature value per day, total of 365 days.
Here is what it looks like:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(filename, engine='netcdf4')
'''
OUTPUT:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (lat: 94, lon: 192, time: 365, nbnds: 2)
Coordinates:
  * lat                 (lat) float32 88.54 86.65 84.75 ... -84.75 -86.65 -88.54
  * lon                 (lon) float32 0.0 1.875 3.75 5.625 ... 354.4 356.2 358.1
  * time                (time) object 0001-01-01 00:00:00 ... 0001-12-31 00:0...
Dimensions without coordinates: nbnds
Data variables:
    climatology_bounds  (time, nbnds) datetime64[ns] ...
    air                 (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    valid_yr_count      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
'''
```

**I need to perform following operations with the dataset**:

1. **extract a subset of a certain time period**

> *(the original dataset's
> timeframe is 0001-01-01 to 0001-12-31; I want a subset, for example,
> 0001-05-01 to 0001-05-05, - a sub-dataset containing 5 daily temperature fields as a result);*

2. **average these subset's daily temperature fields into one mean field** (mean dataset);
3. from the mean dataset then **extract a subset of
   a certain graticule**

> *(the original dataset's graticule is lat: 88.54
> to -88.54 deg., lon: 0.0 to 358.1 deg.; I want it to be, for
> example, lat: 10 to 20 deg., lon: 30 to 50 deg.)*

I'm trying the following thing, - theoretically, this should perform the first two operations:

```
subSet = ds.sel(time=slice('0001-05-01', '0001-05-05')).groupby('nbnds').mean('time')
'''
OUTPUT:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (lat: 94, lon: 192, nbnds: 2)
Coordinates:
  * lat             (lat) float32 88.54 86.65 84.75 ... -84.75 -86.65 -88.54
  * lon             (lon) float32 0.0 1.875 3.75 5.625 ... 354.4 356.2 358.1
Dimensions without coordinates: nbnds
Data variables:
    air             (nbnds, lat, lon) float32 260.7 260.7 260.7 ... 216.4 216.2
    valid_yr_count  (nbnds, lat, lon) float32 30.0 30.0 30.0 ... 30.0 30.0 30.0
'''
```

Then, cropping is the following:

```
cropped = subSet.sel(lat=slice(50, 40), lon=slice(20, 30))
'''
OUTPUT:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (lat: 5, lon: 6, nbnds: 2)
Coordinates:
  * lat             (lat) float32 48.57 46.67 44.76 42.86 40.95
  * lon             (lon) float32 20.62 22.5 24.38 26.25 28.12 30.0
Dimensions without coordinates: nbnds
Data variables:
    air             (nbnds, lat, lon) float32 286.6 286.0 285.3 ... 289.8 287.7
    valid_yr_count  (nbnds, lat, lon) float32 30.0 30.0 30.0 ... 30.0 30.0 30.0
'''
```

As for cropping (third step) it looks correct. But I'm not sure I'm doing it right for the fist part. **Is there a way I could check whether it is correct or not? If it is not, what is the proper way for me?**